# Member Function Pointers and Object Factory Pattern

Tags: c++, function-pointers, factory-pattern, pointer-to-member

I'm working on a project where I need to be able to dynamically spawn objects of a type called `Audio_Device` or types that derive from `Audio_Device`. I have been trying to use a "Factory" pattern in order to achieve this. The idea is that a "ID" string will get registered with the factory as well as a corresponding function pointer to a function that exists inside of `Audio_Device` that spawns a new device. When I call `factory->Create_Device("IdString");` the code should look up the function pointer associated with the ID and call the function via the function pointer and return a new object of the proper type.

I will apologize now for the mass of code to come:

Here is the device factory header:

```
class Device_Factory
    {
    public:

        Device_Factory();
        virtual ~Device_Factory();
        void Register_Device(std::string id,pDevice_Creation_Function pCreateDeviceFunction);
        Audio_Device* Create_Device(std::string id,Memory::Pool* pool=nullptr);
    private:
        std::map<std::string,pDevice_Creation_Function>*m_pFactory_Map;
//map used to get function pointer that will spawn an instance of the class specified with the string key.
        std::map<std::string,pDevice_Creation_Function>::iterator iter;

    };
```

and the implementation:

```
Device_Factory::Device_Factory()
{
    m_pFactory_Map = new std::map<std::string,pDevice_Creation_Function>();
}
Device_Factory::~Device_Factory()
{
    delete m_pFactory_Map;
}

void Device_Factory::Register_Device(std::string id,pDevice_Creation_Function pCreateDeviceFunction){
    m_pFactory_Map->insert(std::make_pair(id,pCreateDeviceFunction));
}
Audio_Device* Device_Factory::Create_Device(std::string id,Memory::Pool* pool){
    iter=m_pFactory_Map->find(id);
    pDevice_Creation_Function p= iter->second;

    //some sort of call to function pointer here
}
```

And now the `Audio_Device` code:

```
class Audio_Device;

    typedef Audio_Device* (Audio_Device:: *pDevice_Creation_Function)(Memory::Pool* pool);
    class Audio_Device: public Device
    {
    protected:
        virtual Audio_Device* Create_Device(Memory::Pool* pool=nullptr);


        /*Functions to describe how the class modifies the audio signal*/
        bool  GetNeedsInputWrite();
        void  SetNeedsInputWrite(bool value);
        bool GetWillModifySignal();
        void SetWillModifySignal(bool value);
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/




    private:
        bool m_requiresInputWriteToProcess;
        bool m_willModifySignal;

        std::map<std::string, void*>* m_pParameters;
        std::map<std::string, void*>::iterator iter;

        /*Read and write buffers*/
        Audio::AudioRingBuffer* m_pInputBuffer;
        Audio::AudioRingBuffer* m_pOutputBuffer;
        /*----------------------*/
    public:
        Audio_Device(Memory::Pool* pool=nullptr);
        virtual ~Audio_Device();

        virtual void* Process(void* data);

        void SetBuffers(Audio::AudioRingBuffer* input,Audio::AudioRingBuffer* output);

        /*Parameter management*/
        void RegisterParameter(std::string id,void* location);
        void* GetParameter(std::string id);
        /*--------------------*/
        constexpr static const pDevice_Creation_Function Device_Creation_Function=&Audio_Device::Create_Device;

    };
    template<typename ParameterType> void AssignToDeviceParameter(std::string parameter_id,ParameterType value,Audio_Device* device)
    {
        *(ParameterType*)device->GetParameter(parameter_id)=value;
    }


}
```

And Implementation:

```
Audio_Device::Audio_Device(Kraken::Memory::Pool* pool):Device::Device(pool)
{
    m_pParameters = new std::map<std::string, void*>();
    SetNeedsInputWrite(false);
    SetWillModifySignal(true);
    m_pInputBuffer=m_pOutputBuffer=nullptr;
}
Audio_Device::~Audio_Device()
{
    delete m_pParameters;
    m_pParameters=nullptr;
    m_pInputBuffer=nullptr;
    m_pOutputBuffer=nullptr;
}
void Audio_Device::SetBuffers(Audio::AudioRingBuffer* input,Audio::AudioRingBuffer* output){
    if (input!=nullptr) {
        m_pInputBuffer=input;
    }
    if (output!=nullptr) {
        m_pOutputBuffer=output;
    }
}
void* Audio_Device::Process(void* data)
{
    /*The Basic Process:
     Wipes input buffer and writes silence to the output buffer.

     the void* data can be used to pass information to the function. in this implementation the function merely passes the adress of the data back in order to complete the return for the function.
     */
    m_pInputBuffer->Flush();
    Audio::Sample_Stereo_d samp;
    samp.m_Channel_1=0;
    samp.m_Channel_2=0;
    for (int i =0; i<m_pOutputBuffer->Buffer_Size(); ++i) {
        m_pOutputBuffer->Push(&samp);
    }
    return data;
}

bool Audio_Device::GetNeedsInputWrite(){
    return m_requiresInputWriteToProcess;
}
void Audio_Device::SetNeedsInputWrite(bool value){
    m_requiresInputWriteToProcess=value;
}
bool Audio_Device::GetWillModifySignal(){
    return m_willModifySignal;
}
void Audio_Device::SetWillModifySignal(bool value){
    m_willModifySignal=value;
}
void Audio_Device::RegisterParameter(std::string id,void* location){
    m_pParameters->insert(std::make_pair(id, location));
}
void* Audio_Device::GetParameter(std::string id){
    iter= m_pParameters->find(id);
    return iter->second;
}
Audio_Device* Audio_Device::Create_Device(Memory::Pool* pool){
    return new(pool)Audio_Device(pool);
}
```

I have some namespace business and memory pooling going on so please ignore that. 
The goal is to be able to have code like this:

```
Device_Factory* factory = new Device_Factory();
factory->Register_Device("ID", Audio_Device::Device_Creation_Function);
```

That will register the parameter.(this works right now)And then have the `Audio_Device* Create_Device(std::string id,Memory::Pool* pool=nullptr);` function perform code like this:

```
Audio_Device* Device_Factory::Create_Device(std::string id,Memory::Pool* pool){
    iter=m_pFactory_Map->find(id);
    pDevice_Creation_Function p= iter->second;
//where pDevice_Creation_Function is a member function pointer.
//and then somehow call it to return a new object.
}
```

My main issue is that all of the various member function call syntax's i have found do not seem to work. For example `(device.*Device_Creation_Function)(args)` does not work for me.
So what is the proper way to call a member function pointer? or what is a better way to achieve the concept i have attempted to describe?

Any help of any kind would be great, and let me know if i can provide clarification because  I know that i am throwing a stack of code at you.

Thanks

Comment: In your map container, you could instead use the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) to create an instance of whatever Audio class you'd like.

Comment: Could you give me a code example of how that might look with my code?

Comment: iter=m_pFactory_Map->find(id);  if(iter != m_pFactory_Map->end()) { return iter->second->createNewInstance(); }  // For example.

Comment: but how would that work? my map at the moment is defined as`std::map<std::string,pDevice_Creation_Function>` so `iter` would be a function pointer. are you suggesting that i hold types in the map instead of the function pointer? the issue that i see is that each derived class will have to be able to spawn an instance of itself. That is why the creation function is virtual and the function pointer points to is. the function pointer is `static` and `const` so it will always point to the function but the function will still be able to be modified to spawn the correct class.

Answer (score 1):

They not work because they really not works in such situation.
The "device" creation function should be like usual non-member function. It may be a static member (clearly, trivial wrapper for "new"). No member function call syntax should be used, no "virtual constructor" are existing :-)
Second, it may be better simple construct the desired object of proper derived class as necessary (by "new"). Do you sure you really need the "Factory" and string id's?
Also the map which constructed by "new" in constructor and deleted in destructor may be better the data member, not the pointer...
And parameters map in AudioDevice are some questionable. Do really AudioDevice class should manipulate unknown parameters of type void*? May be they are members of derived class (where they will have an appropriate names and proper types and will be properly manipulated)?

Comment: The parameter map is for a different part of the system. The project is a Digital Audio Workstation and these devices represent different audio plugins. the idea is that the guy handler will know the id of the parameter and the type, and therefore has the neccesary info to assign to the variable. it is just a means of grouping different types of parameters together neatlly. As far as the device factory, could you give me a code example of what you are describing?

Comment: `class X : public B { public: static B * newX(MemPool *p) { return new X(p); } X(MemPool *); /* ... */ }; /* the newX is the function you need. It may be ever not a member and called as necessary. "new X(pool)" may be better. */`

Answer (score 1):

Member function pointers work fine with virtual functions, but you need an object to call them on.

Which conflicts with the purpose of using that function to create the object in the first place.